# Merging Thousand of .*xlsx

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to merge thousands of Excel Files into one. This is the structures of the files:

[image: Excel 1]

[image: Excel 2]

What I want to achieve is combination between them such as :
[image: Result]

Basically to combine them based on Header Name. If I miss a header in a file the line in the column to be empty.
My tables start always from the 13th line but I need information from above so I am splitting the information into two dataframes and include the information from the first into rows of second:

Note that columns in the excel tables are in different places!
I am trying by using pandas:

```
dfs=[]
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    df1 = df.iloc[:12]
    df2 = df.iloc[13:]
    df2.columns = df2.iloc[0]
    df2 = df2.iloc[1:]
    df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
    df2.head()
    try:
        for item in df1['Unnamed: 2']:
            df2[str(df1['Unnamed: 1'][counter])]=str(item)
            counter += 1
    except Exception as e:
        print("Problem: ",e,file)
    df2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    dfs.append(df2)

  
#Then I try to concatinate the files with the following:
df =pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True,axis=0)
```

But Unfortunately I get the following error :
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Can someone help me to solve the issue, please?

Comment: Don't you overwrite the whole data frame by doing `df=df.iloc[1:]`? All the column stuff is gone

Answer (score 0):

You can set the header row using an argument. I would read the data stored above the column names separately as the data types will not be interpreted correctly otherwise:

```
dfs = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file, header=12)
    
    header = pd.read_excel(file, 
                           nrows=3, 
                           skiprows=1, 
                           header=None, 
                           usecols=[1,2], 
                           index_col=1).transpose()

    for col in header.columns:
        df[col] = header[col].values[0]
        
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: But in my case the table starts from the 13th line and I am trying to set the headers.
This is what I do
'''
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    df1 = df.iloc[:12]
    df2 = df.iloc[13:]
    df2.columns = df2.iloc[0]
    df2 = df2.iloc[1:]
    df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
    df2.head()
    counter = 0
    try:
        for item in df1['Unnamed: 2']:
            df2[str(df1['Unnamed: 1'][counter])]=str(item)
            counter += 1
    except Exception as e:
        print("Problem: ",e,file)
    df2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    dfs.app...
'''

Comment: This was not clear in the original question but I've updated the answer to reflect it. The code has not been tested as there was no sample data available.